# Set the nameserver in ubuntu with netplan

Tags: 18.04, netplan, resolvconf

I'm working on an `ansible playbook` to set the dns server addresses in my `Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.2` server.

I don't want to use `resolv.conf` cause I learned it's deprecated in the new Ubuntu.

My question is: Is there an easy way to set the nameservers with `netplan` or `ip link set` utility without changing files (cause is not that simple with ansible)?

Comment: Please refer [Netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject nameservers at runtime using the `resolvectl` tool.  However, note that these settings will not persist across reboots of the target system.  It is probably better to emit your config to a separate file under /etc/netplan/ that you manage exclusively with ansible, and which lists only the dns server settings that you wish to provide, and then call `netplan apply`, so that the setting persists across reboot.